# Software for creation of 3D models of humans?

Tags: 3d, modeling

**Background**

I've recently read about plastic surgery and came across the information, that a lot of doctors make use of 3D models to show their patients what to expect. I understand that there are [3D scanners](http://www.canfieldsci.com/imaging-systems/vectra-m3-3d-imaging-system/) involved most of the time though.

**What I want to do**

Since I have some experience creating 3D models with [3D Studio Max][2] and [Inventor][3], and I also have a some free time ahead, I thought about modeling myself in 3D. Preferably in a way, that I can change certain parameters to alter my look digitally and play around a little.

**What I know so far**

I came across [Smith Mirco Software Poser](http://my.smithmicro.com/poser-11.html), which seems to be the perfect fit. However it costs around 80$ for students, which I am not yet willing to pay without knowing what to expect.
I already have 3D Studio Max at my disposal, but it seems a litte too difficult to get the results there (assuming that I use box modeling).

**Which software would you suggest?**

Comment: DAZ often has discounts on their models. http://www.daz3d.com/home

Answer (score 2):

Personally I cannot recommend [Blender 3D](https://www.blender.org/) modeller enough.

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Contains just about everything that you might need
- Lots of books, tutorials, online demo, user groups, etc.
- Programmatic model construction & variation from within Blender
- There are even lots of free or paid for models to use as a starting point, e.g. [here](https://www.blender-models.com/model-downloads/humans/).
- Includes Armature modelling so that you can make sure that the articulation is correct.
- Includes Animation, Lighting, Texturing, basically everything.

It does have a bit of a steep learning curve but once that is surmounted the results that are possible are incredible.

Comment: I never really looked at Blender since I have access to a free student license of Autodesk 3D Studio Max. But after your answer I checked out a few tutorials of Blender and was convinced that it is a valid alternative to 3D Studio Max. Especially the availability of free models to start with seems an interesting option.